# unable to retrieve the elastic search reindexing task details getting error "malformed task id"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have initiated the reindexing of a large index using the command.

```
curl -XPOST https://<SERVER_HOST_NAME>/_reindex  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destination_index"
  }
}'
```

The problem is I am unable to know the status of the indexing operation at runtime.

I am using the task API to get the list of tasks.

```
https://<SERVER_HOST_NAME>/_tasks
```

and I can see the reindexing task.

```
"<nodename>:8793524": {
                    "node": "<nodename>",
                    "id": 8793524,
                    "type": "transport",
                    "action": "indices:data/write/reindex",
                    "start_time_in_millis": 1619678127505,
                    "running_time_in_nanos": 6776632132,
                    "cancellable": true,
                    "headers": {}
                }
```

But when i use this task id to get the status of the task from the postman (endpoint: https://<SERVER_HOST_NAME>/_tasks /8793524)  it gives me an error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "malformed task id 8793524"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "malformed task id 8793524"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the node name just before the task ID, like this:

```
https://<SERVER_HOST_NAME>/_tasks/<nodename>:8793524
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked and i am able to view the status.

Comment: I think the problem is in the name of the attribute in response of /_task api. It has been named as id, but actually, it is a task number.

Comment: I think it should be `GET /_tasks/node_name:taskId` rather than `GET /_tasks/taskId:1` in the example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api